# Edit local Mac web server files from a Windows machine on the same LAN

Tags: windows-7, mac, local

I am running my test sites on my mac, but I would like be able to use my windows machine to also access this server and be able to write / read fiels form this server.

I can access my sites on my windows by using the IP address 192.168.1.???.

But I would like to be able to use my windows machine to also access the fiels and edit them.

Any ideas much appreciated.

Some details:
Mac OSX SL file sharing set to on.
Windows 7 (tried setting up network map using afp://192.... but nothing)

Both machines are connected to a local network, with several other machine (windows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows speaks SMB for file sharing, not AFP. Try enabling SMB file sharing on the Mac. [This guide](http://macs.about.com/od/filesharing/ss/file-sharing-with-snow-leopard-win7.htm) will show you how, if you don't know already.

Comment: thansk for the reply, but i get to the end and it then leaves out waht i then need to do on the windows 7 PC.  I set up the mac bu then whats required on the PC sorry if missing something

Comment: Forget it, i was tryin gto connect via ip and it would not let me as i had to browse for it.  Many Thanks for this